# Isomorphism from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the space $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be non-empty such that $I$ is in general not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. it is not necessarily closed under addition and multiplication by a scalar. We define a projection from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ by $\alpha(\boldsymbol{x}) = (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$, where $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n), \ \boldsymbol{x} \in I$.

We know that the following property holds for $\alpha$, which follows from the properties of $I$: for $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y} \in I$, if $\alpha(\boldsymbol{x}) = \alpha(\boldsymbol{y})$, then $\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y}$.

The paper I read shows that $\dim(I) = n-1$ and thus the Lebesgue measure of $I$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $0$. Its reasoning is that $\alpha$ is an *epimorphism* since it is a projection and a *monomorphism* by the aforementioned property, so it is an *isomorphism*.

My questions are:

1. Which definition of an *isomorphism* is used here at all? (I am mostly familiar with the definition of an *isomorphism* between two vector spaces).
2. Is it true to state that $\alpha$ is an *isomorphism* because it is a bijection (i.e. leaving out the notions of  *epimorphism* and *monomorphism*)?
3. If no, which definitions of *epimorphism* and *monomorphism* are used here and why these two properties imply that $\alpha$ is an *isomorphism*?

References to definitions and theorems in books are also appreciated very much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $I$ as the graph of a function $$f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R},\: (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\to f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}).$$ That is,

$$I=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_n=f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\}.$$ Assuming $f$ is continuous then isomorphism should mean homeomorphism. If $f$ is not continuous, then isomorphism would be just bijection.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Would it help knowing that $I$ is a level set of a function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which is strictly increasing in each component (i.e., $I = \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: F(\boldsymbol{x}) = q \}$, where $q \in F(\mathbb{R}^n))$? This is the only assumption made in the paper.

Comment: What is the paper you are reading?

Comment: It is in Italian...

Comment: Is it available online?

Comment: I only have a scanned version from the author: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2w95ixtoklrn00c/Insiemi%201990.pdf?dl=0. The corresponding proposition is named Property 3 ("Proprieta 3").

Comment: To me it is talking of *morphism of sets, that is: monomorphism means injective, epimorphism means surjective and isomorphism means bijective. There is no additional structure on the proof.

Comment: This is what puzzles me. If they are talking about isomorphism of sets, then it does not imply anything about the dimension of $I$ (does it?). And they are certainly not talking about isomorphism of vector spaces, since $I$ is not a vector space. So I don't get what they are talking about...

Comment: I agree with you. The dimension is used later when assume that $I_q$ is convex. In this case it makes sense, because it is an affine space. But, to me, it is unnecessary in Propieta 3.